# Angular 4 in old browser

Tags: angular, browser

is there any ways to make angular 4 application run in old browser?

because when i run my application that is not supported [here](https://v4.angular.io/guide/browser-support) it's only return blank screen

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected browser?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam old Firefox and Chrome or IE 8?

Comment: I am not sure about IE8 but for me it worked down to IE 11 by removing the comments of es6 modules from polyfills.ts

Comment: @AshrafulIslam IE 11 is supported if refer to this https://v4.angular.io/guide/browser-support